# How to set children state based on parent state passed with props in React

Tags: reactjs

I have a parent component:

```
interface AlbumListProps {
    albums: AlbumType[];
}

const AlbumList = (props: AlbumListProps) => {
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

    let albumToEdit;

    const handleEdit = () => {
        setOpen(true);
    };

    return (
        <>
          <button onClick={handleEdit} > Edit </button>
          <Modal openModal={open} />
        </>
    );
};
```

And child component which is a modal window.

```
const Modal = (props: any) => {
    const { openModal } = props;
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(openModal);

    const cancelButtonRef = useRef(null);

    return (
      <Transition.Root show={open} as={Fragment}>
        <Dialog as='div' initialFocus={cancelButtonRef} onClose={setOpen} >
          <Transition.Child as={Fragment} > 
           <Dialog.Panel>
            <Dialog.Title> Some text </Dialog.Title>
            <button type='button' onClick={() => setOpen(false)} 
                  ref={cancelButtonRef} > Cancel </button> 
            </Dialog.Panel>
          </Transition.Child>
        </Dialog>
      </Transition.Root>
    );
};
```

As you can see I'm passing true with `onClick={handleEdit}` via `openModal` props down to Modal component.
 In Modal component I'm setting up the initial state with the value received from props.openModal, unfortunately, the modal window don't open.

I think the issue is in `AlbumList` component as when I'm setting up open to `true` with `const [open, setOpen] = useState(true)` Modal window shows up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the initial state of the child component is only set once when the component is first rendered.

you can make it update each time `openModal` is updated:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  setOpen(openModal);
},[openModal]);
```

---

you can also use `openModal` directly you don't really need create a state in the child component and here:

```js
<button type='button' onClick={() => props.setOpen(false)}> Cancel </button>
```

with passing also `setOpen` function as props to to child:

```js
<Modal 
 openModal={open} 
 setOpen={setOpen}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

why not just skip the second set of state and do...

```
...return (
     <Transition.Root show={openModal} as={Fragment}>...
```

That way is more efficient and easier to follow / debug.

Comment: Tried this way but I could'n set the open value to false from button onClick.

Answer (score 0):

You could change this:

```js
const handleEdit = () => {
        setOpen(true);
    };
```

to this:

```js
const handleEdit = () => setOpen(!open);
```

and then pass `handleEdit` as prop to `Modal`. Then your `onClick` prop for the button inside `Modal` would be `handleEdit`.